# Why are resistances measured in mutually orthogonal directions in Van der Pauw method?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance

In [Van der Pauw method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Pauw_method), two resistances are measured in orthogonal directions to each other. These are used to calculate sheet resistance from the Van der Pauw equation. Why is it that resistances are measured specifically in mutually orthogonal directions? I tried finding an answer in different papers, online sources and by looking at the derivation of the van der Pauw equation. I didn't really find the answer.

Comment: From the wikipedia entry on the Van der Pauw method: "In his paper, van der Pauw showed that the sheet resistance of samples with arbitrary shapes can be determined from two of these resistances - one measured along a vertical edge, such as R 12, 34 , and a corresponding one measured along a horizontal edge, such as R 23, 41". Does that answer your question?

Comment: Strictly speaking it doesn't seem they need to be orthogonal, as the procedure is supposed to work for samples of arbitrary shape (assuming certain conditions are met)

Comment: Yes, measurement is explained in terms of mutually orthogonal directions. Whether that is only an example or a requirement, I'm not really sure.

Comment: Does my answer below answer your question? If so you can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Van der Pauw method does not require measurements along orthogonal directions. In fact, reading the original paper [2], you will see that the method works for samples of arbitrary shape (even the title says so).

The paper assumes the following:

1. The measurement contacts are at the circumference of the sample.
2. The contacts are sufficiently small.
3. The sample is homogeneuous in thickness.
4. The surface of the sample is singly [sic] connected, i.e., the sample does not have isolated holes.

It then proves that for *any* shape satisfying these conditions (see the screenshot below for the example shape from the paper), we have

$e^{-\pi R_{AB,CD} \frac{d}{\rho}} + e^{-\pi R_{BC,DA} \frac{d}{\rho}} = 1$,

where $\rho$ is the desired specific resistance of the sample, and $d$ the thickness. The resistance $R_{AB,CD}$ is defined as the potential difference $V_D - V_C$ between the contacts $D$ and $C$ per unit current through the contacts $A$ and $B$.

[image: Sample of arbitrary shape]

I think this is a good example of why it is important to check primary sources. The confusion seems to have arisen because of the ambiguous use of the terms 'horizontal' and 'vertical' in the wikipedia article (which someone should fix). Looking at the image above you can see why one would refer to the measurements in that way, but they aren't *literally* horizontal or vertical, and in any case definitely aren't orthogonal.

**Bibliography**

[2] Philips’Gloeilampenfabrieken, O. "A method of measuring specific resistivity and Hall effect of discs of arbitrary shape." Philips Res. Rep 13.1 (1958): 1-9.

Comment: Yes, it's always good to check the original work. I'm not sure if I understood it correctly, but, it's not about the direction per se, it's about measuring 2 currents along the sample edge. We also want to make sure that in both measurements, when we change the current and voltage probes, that they are placed at the same points to keep the distances between the probes the same?

Comment: That sounds like a different question... but from what I understand yes, you need to make sure the points A to D remain the same for the two measurements.